# How to set cell's dataType to Number using ExcelPackage lib?

Tags: c#, export-to-excel

My question is probably a stupid one, but I can't find solution on my own.
I've run into a problem with ([ExcelPackage](http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/)). Is there any way to set cell's Excel data type ? And the cell.DataType property is string so which DataTypes are allowed ? Basically I need to set numeric formatting for certain columns/cells.

Thanks for the time spend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a forum post that seems to answer your question:
http://excelpackage.codeplex.com/discussions/50205?ProjectName=excelpackage

It looks like the Excel document should detect which type of data you are entering into the cell but if you want to override that, the above link should help you out.  Unfortunately, it isn't simple to do so.

Answer (score 3):

I needed to show numeric values like text, then I added an empty string (" ") at the end of my value. i.e:

```
xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Cell(contRow, contCol).Value = "08 ";
```

Also, the cell (`contRow`, `contCol`) was formatted like Text.
And this work for me.
I hope this is useful for you.

Comment: This works, but leaves a horrible after taste.
If i set the style of the cell to one that has a Number format of 'Text', Excel ignores the formatting (but applies the style) when opening the document. So annoying to find another one of those 'That seems logical - and simple - but why doesn't it just work' coding issues that waste more time than could possibly be imagined.